# web scraping with beautifulsoup hiding elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the following url with `BeautifulSoup`:
https://www.investopedia.com/markets/stocks/aapl/#Financials

I have tried to parse this section which i found with inspect:

```
     <div class="value">
          <div class="marker position" style="left: 89.25%;"></div>
          <div class="text position" style="left: 89.25%;">1.43</div>
     </div>
```

MyCode is as followed:

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

def load_ticker_invest(ticker):
resp = requests.get('https://www.investopedia.com/markets/stocks/{}/#Financials'.format(ticker))
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
    trend = soup.div.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'value'})

    return trend

print (load_ticker_invest('aapl'))
```

What I get as result is a blank list:

```
[]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I can't check now (on my phone), but are you sure this HTML is actually in the HTML source, or pulled from some API with Javascript? If the latter then you can't get it by scraping and will have to use the API directly (which is usually easier, assuming they allow public access).

Comment: I just checked on my laptop - searching for "marker-position" after viewing source yields nothing, even though like you I can see that HTML by inspecting. So as I said it must be dynamically generated on the client side. At least one of their minified JS files has a bunch of Ajax calls in it, unfortunately a lot of it is obfuscated so I haven't yet found the URL of where the particular data you're chasing is coming from.

Comment: it is not in HTML source and think it is pulled from API, could you tell me how can i access the API?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, it's not a site I ever use, I know nothing about trading or investments :) I don't see a better way than digging through the site's javascript code and trying to figure out which URL it is being derived from - but that is no easy task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import bs4 as bs

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
driver.get('https://www.investopedia.com/markets/stocks/aapl/#Financials')
resp = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')
driver.quit()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser')
res = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'text position'}).text
print (res)
```

Answer (score 1):

This site uses an internal API to get those data, this API call needs some tokens that are embedded in some Javascript script inside the page https://www.investopedia.com/markets/stocks/aapl so you need first to scrap those values  using some regex and then use them in the API call

Using a bash script with [curl](/questions/tagged/curl), [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), [tr](/questions/tagged/tr) and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```
title=aapl

IFS=' ' read token token_userid < <(curl -s "https://www.investopedia.com/markets/stocks/$title/" | \
     tr -d '\n' | \
     sed -rn "s:.*Xignite\(\s*'([A-Z0-9]+)',\s*'([A-Z0-9]+)'.*:\1 \2:p")

curl -s "https://factsetestimates.xignite.com/xFactSetEstimates.json/GetLatestRecommendationSummaries?IdentifierType=Symbol&Identifiers=$title&UpdatedSince=&_token=$token&_token_userid=$token_userid" | \
     jq -r '.[].RecommendationSummarySet | .[].RecommendationScore'
```

Using [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```
import requests
import re

ticker = 'aapl'

r = requests.get('https://www.investopedia.com/markets/stocks/{}/'.format(ticker))

result = re.search(r".*Xignite\(\s*'([A-Z0-9]+)',\s*'([A-Z0-9]+)'", r.text)

token = result.group(1)
token_userid = result.group(2)

r = requests.get('https://factsetestimates.xignite.com/xFactSetEstimates.json/GetLatestRecommendationSummaries?IdentifierType=Symbol&Identifiers={}&UpdatedSince=&_token={}&_token_userid={}'
    .format(ticker, token, token_userid)
)

print(r.json()[0]['RecommendationSummarySet'][0]['RecommendationScore'])
```

Comment: Yes, it works very well. Selenium works as well but, your code seems to be much better.

Comment: @KeyvanTajbakhsh I think in this case you should stick to selenium solution since the solution above use regex which can break very fast if small upgrade are made on this site